# Apache Client-cache jar

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat, jira

I' trying to use Jira Rest Java Client's jar and have ran into a few bumps.
I'm getting this error for a while now:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.CacheConfig.setNeverCache1_0ResponsesWithQueryString(Z)V
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:155)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousHttpClientFactory.createClient(AsynchronousHttpClientFactory.java:53)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.create(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:35)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:41)
    at com.backend.server.HomeController.commitIssue(HomeController.java:1517)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Now, I have a jar of httpclient-cache-4.3-beta2.jar, but that only has the desired method inside a Builder object in the CacheConfig class, as far as I can see..

Can anyone point me to the right dependency for his?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know my reply is late. But still I gave a great fight on my own and found the correct jar file for this

Download [httpclient-cache-4.2.1-atlassian-2.jar](https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.apache.httpcomponents%3ahttpclient-cache/4.2.1-atlassian-2)