# How do I solve a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory?

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-java-api

Exception: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/atlassian/jira/rest/client/internal/async/AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory`

I searched everywhere but don't know how to solve it. I want to fetch **`JIRA`** data.

I am using similar code to
http://invariantproperties.com/2013/08/07/using-the-jira-rest-java-client-introduction/

I am getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/atlassian/jira/rest/client/internal/async/AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1287)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Root cause:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/atlassian/jira/rest/client/internal/async/AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory
    jira.HelloWorldController.jiramethod(HelloWorldController.java:58)
    jira.HelloWorldController.handleRequestInternal(HelloWorldController.java:32)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:154)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

This is caused by:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    jira.HelloWorldController.jiramethod(HelloWorldController.java:58)
    jira.HelloWorldController.handleRequestInternal(HelloWorldController.java:32)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:154)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I don't know what to do.

I am new to **`JIRA`** and I have been searching for the solution for the last 2 days.

Comment: You're missing a JAR on your classpath. The paifull truth is that you will have to find out which one. This was the closest I could find: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24388543/460557

Comment: This one is better: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/199648/rest-java-client-library-maven-dependency

Comment: Hi, can you post your `pom.xml` file?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.openengsb.wrapped</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-m32.w1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openengsb.wrapped</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-m32.w1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```