# find the Issue from JIRA using java

Tags: java, maven, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

I am trying to connect with JIRA and create issue.I have written the same code but i got some issue.

**pom.xml**

```
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
          <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

          <groupId>com.fis.poc</groupId>
          <artifactId>JIRATEST1</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <packaging>jar</packaging>

          <name>JIRATEST1</name>
          <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

          <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
          </properties>

          <dependencies>
          <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.sal/sal-api -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.sal/sal-api -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.sal</groupId>
            <artifactId>sal-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1-atlassian-2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.sal</groupId>
            <artifactId>sal-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.atlassian.httpclient</groupId>
           <artifactId>atlassian-httpclient-spi</artifactId>
           <version>0.17.0-m01</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore-nio</artifactId>
            <version>4.0-alpha6</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore-nio</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.5</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-httpclient-apache-httpcomponents</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-httpclient-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.23.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.event</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-event</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.util.concurrent</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-util-concurrent</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.8.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
                <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

             <dependency>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
                <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>14.0-rc1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
                <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>


        </project>
```

And i write java code for fetch the information about some issue. Which is already created in JIRA.I have put the static variables for URI and username and password.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Issue issue = getIssue("TEST_12332");
    }   

    public static Issue getIssue(String issueKey) throws Exception{
            final URI jiraServerUri = new URI(JIRA_URL);
            final JiraRestClient restClient = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory().createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME, JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD);
            Promise issuePromise = restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue(issueKey);
            return (Issue)issuePromise.claim();
          //  return Optional.ofNullable((Issue) issuePromise.claim()).orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("No such issue"));
     }
```

But i got error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.CacheConfig.setNeverCache1_0ResponsesWithQueryString(Z)V
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:155)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousHttpClientFactory.createClient(AsynchronousHttpClientFactory.java:53)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.create(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:35)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:42)
    at com.fis.poc.JIRATEST1.JiraTest.getIssue(JiraTest.java:37)
    at com.fis.poc.JIRATEST1.JiraTest.main(JiraTest.java:28)
```

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249767/apache-client-cache-jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now its working fine,My was wrong i needed to add https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public repository in my pom.I thing Because of unavailability of repository incorrect jar was downloaded.Now my pom is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.fis.poc</groupId>
  <artifactId>jiraClientApp1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>jiraClientApp1</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>14.0-rc1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

     <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>atlassian-public</id>
            <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>atlassian-public</id>
            <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```